# PancakeSwap Error with Brownie, revert: TransferHelper::transferFrom: transferFrom failed

Tags: brownie, pancakeswap

I am in `bsc-testnet` and have 0.3 `WBNB` in my wallet and I try to swap 0.1 `WBNB` for `USDT` with the function `swapExactTokensForTokens()`

```
Token1 = '0xae13d989daC2f0dEbFf460aC112a837C89BAa7cd'
Token2 = '0xeD24FC36d5Ee211Ea25A80239Fb8C4Cfd80f12Ee'

Pancakerouter = interface.IPancakeRouter01('0x9Ac64Cc6e4415144C455BD8E4837Fea55603e5c3')

Executeswap = Pancakerouter.swapExactTokensForTokens(
        Web3.toWei(0.1, "ether"),
        0,
        [Token1,Token2],
        account,
        int(time.time()) + 10 * 600,
        {"from": account, "gas_limit": 10000000, "allow_revert": True},
    )
Executeswap.wait(1)
```

Here is my error and tx: `VirtualMachineError: revert: TransferHelper::transferFrom: transferFrom failed`
`https://testnet.bscscan.com/tx/0x6c8a7b802863afc92f61195dc952de1cb21d9b65b6df4205d5ad2e4a6813ed36`

Answer (score 1):

You're not approving the router to spend your WBNB. I never used brownie (or really done anything remotely complex in python, tbf x') ) so no idea how to code that exactly, but the idea is that you wanna send an `approve(routerAddress, amountYouWantToSwap)` transaction to the WBNB contract.